# Best practices for split testing Android apps

Tags: android, testing, multivariate-testing

For web applications split testing various options get usually split tested to maximize their effectiveness with tools like Google Website Optimizer. One of the most impressive example might be Google and how the split tested dozens of shades of blue to find the right one.

When developing android applications are there best practices to follow for A/B testing or multivariate testing?

Answer (score 2):

Came here first then continued down the results and came across an [elegant answer](http://groups.diigo.com/group/android_related/content/tip-google-i-o-2011-apply-a-b-testing-to-your-android-app-2811611).
(Vincent Tsao on 12 May 11)

```
private static final boolean isA = UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits() % 2 == 0; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

   if(isA){ 
       setContentView(R.layout.mainA); 
       MyApp.getInstance().tracker().trackPageView("/AUser"); 
   }else{ 
       setContentView(R.layout.mainB); 
       MyApp.getInstance().tracker().trackPageView("/BUser"); 
   } 
   ... 
}
```

My only thought is to save the choice so they return to the same layout each time.

Answer (score 0):

I was just considering this (hence the Google search that brought me here).  My search hasn't yielded and frameworks.

If you know before you launch what you'd like to test, it's pretty simple (in theory).  Phone home when you start up and ask if the app should show A or B (and send along which cohort the user was in when you send results).

More likely, the app has been out for a week, and now you want to start testing variations.  You could upload a new version, and that's not a terrible idea.  But if you're not willing to restrict yourself to people who update your app, it seems you CAN download classes from the web and load them dynamically:

http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html

Of course, you'll need to know what to do with the class you downloaded.  I would guess your app would phone home for updates, and then download both a dex file and a description file that says which class it should replace.

I haven't tried this myself.  Whatever you do with this, I have a feeling it will not be straightforward.

Answer (score -3):

The best workaround would be to build a mobile app accessible through mobile web browser. So you could implement a/b resource like optimizely or something. You loose the benefit of having the native app feel though. If you are trying to a/b testing native app like you would on the web. I'm sorry you are out of luck, well at least to  my knowledge